# MySQL: How do I get to a column of another table via a mapping table

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a database for assignments where there is a table for the tasks, a table for the persons and a table for the assignment of a person to a task.
Now I have tried to access the task table with a select statement and at the same time get all assigned persons but nothing worked. (because a task is also assigned to other tables) 
Is there a way or do I have to use several statements for this?

This is how i created my Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Locations (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, LocationID VARCHAR(255),
                        PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE TABLE Persons (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, FirstName VARCHAR(255), LastName     
                      VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE TABLE Tasks (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT , TaskName VARCHAR(255), LocationID 
                    INT, PRIMARY KEY (ID),
                    FOREIGN KEY (LocationID) REFERENCES Locations(ID));

CREATE TABLE Assinment (TaskID INT, PersonID INT,
                        PRIMARY KEY (TaskID, PersonID), FOREIGN KEY (TaskID) 
                        REFERENCES Tasks(ID), FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) 
                        REFERENCES Persons(ID));
```

And this is the [UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gob7T.png).

I do not want my joins on the Assinment table like

```
SELECT (FirstName, LastName, TaskName) FROM ((Assinment INNER JOIN Tasks ON 
Assinment.TaskID = Tasks.ID) INNER JOIN Persons ON Assinment.PersonID = 
Persons.ID)
```

because the tasks table has more joins (e.g. locations and priorities) so i want my query start with

```
SELECT (ID, TaskName, FirstName, LastName, LocationName) FROM Tasks [...]
```

so i can get all data by id of the task

The Output then should give me this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl3sK.png).

Thanks for help :)

*EDIT*

Ouput added and desired input is now more specified

Comment: "I do not want something like"...why not, exactly? That query looks like it should do the job (apart from some syntax problems). If you restrict it to a specific task using a WHERE clause, then you'll get all the people assigned to that task. `SELECT FirstName, LastName, TaskName 
FROM Assinment 
INNER JOIN Tasks ON 
Assinment.TaskID = Tasks.ID 
INNER JOIN Persons ON Assinment.PersonID = 
Persons.ID
WHERE Tasks.ID = 1` for example. Note the absence of superfluous brackets compared to your example, these will cause a syntax error in mysql

Comment: Your query looks like MS Access syntax.  To get an exact answer here, you should show us what your expected output looks like.

Comment: Marked down because, if you don't want to use a join, I think you really need to tell us why not.

Comment: Hi. Clearly say what the output is supposed to be given the input. (Not a vauge sentence re what you want & an example of code for what you don't want.) Read & act on [mcve]. PS Please format code clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try subqueries :

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name1
WHERE value IN (SELECT column-name
                   FROM table-name2 
                  WHERE condition)
```